# loading order of elpa and init.el

Tags: emacs24

I've pulled the starter-kit from https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit, and it was installed in `~/.emacs.d/elpa`. Following the instruction of the `starter-kit.el`, I put my user-specific customization in `~/.emacs.d/$USER.el`:

```
(require 'color-theme-solarized)
(color-theme-solarized-dark)
(require 'auto-complete)
(global-auto-complete-mode)
```

But when I started emacs, it says

```
File error: Cannot open load file, color-theme-solarized
```

I checked the `load-path` variable and found that the path of `color-theme-solarized` wasn't in it. So I add this before "require" it:

```
 (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/color-theme-solarized-20120301)
```

However the error still occurs.Then I referred to elpa's wiki and it says that all the packages are initialized after the `init.el` is loaded. Then I read the `starter-kit.el` and found that **the `$USER.el` is added to `after-init-hook`**, which means that the error shouldn't occur since the `$USER.el` is loaded at the end of initializing. I desperately move all my customization to the end of `init.el`, to my surprise, it just work fine. It seems that the `init.el` is loaded at last rather than at first.
How could I make my customization work except writing it in the `init.el`? I don't want to make the `init.el` too long.

ps: I've put `(require 'package)` and `(package-initialize)` at the beginning of `init.el`
and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I use emacs-starter-kit or emacs24-starter-kit. It is really good. Install it first and follow the instructions. Then open emacs do what ever you need. You only need to manage one file $USER.org if you want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

ELPA adds autoloads for your packages. I don't use themes, but typically you would do something like `(eval-after-load "color-theme" (quote (color-theme-solarized)))`, or, if you want it to run after it has just autoloaded (but not fully loaded),  `(eval-after-load "color-theme-autoloads" (quote (color-theme-solarized)))`.

Comment: Well, I'm now using the configuration from Steve Purcell, and it just works fine. Thanks, though.